# how to check google analytics KPI in my platform

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, kpi

I am developing a platform which will be used as a digital media planner. you can come to the platform, create your campaign, and set KPI s for it. now i want to connect it to google analytics in a way that you can check if your KPI s are being met or not, if not be notified and do some changes.

so this platform should be connected to google analytics and check if KPI is met or not. how can I connect to google analytics in this way? I search about google analytics API and all i get is that piece of code that you should put in different website code so you can monitor them.

but i want to check the monitoring of my websites by the analytics , in the background and give the suitable advice if something in the advertising campaign is going wrong.
how can I do that?

Comment: You should look into the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). It is a way in which you can retrieve the information stored in Google Analytics.

Comment: @Matt you should post your comment as an answer because it completely solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). It is a way in which a user can authorize your application to retrieve the information stored in Google Analytics.